# Parallel file uploading using azure blob storage javascript library (v12)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

How to upload multiple files parallelly to Azure Storage account using azure javascript library(v12) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what methods support parallel uploading, in the library for JavaScript description, there functions only available in Node.js:[Features, interfaces, classes or functions only available in Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/9a5733edb0a50ee0fd9f8f83951a0e8860a95620/sdk/storage/storage-blob/README.md#features-interfaces-classes-or-functions-only-available-in-nodejs).

**Parallel uploading and downloading**

- BlockBlobClient.uploadFile()
- BlockBlobClient.uploadStream()

If you wanna a sample you could refer to here:https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/112c8e28a3876b1a47bc688b7756150113a0e8a0/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/advanced.js#L59.